# Client_id rejected when login SE

Tags: discussion

Application Login Failure
An error occurred while login into an application.

Error Details

error description: client_id rejected

I login with yahoo account, failed as above:(

Comment: Why not just add openID login to normal style like google account?

Comment: I have the same issue when I try to log in using OpenID.